# What does a report without landing page mean?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

If there is no user landing on the page, then why does Google Analytics 4 show the sources in the report?

[image]

Comment: You may send a sample URL to explain the problem more.

Comment: What sample URL should I use?

Comment: I suspect this is your homepage. You could verify with an Explorer report and look at the landing page dimension along with the page location. That should give you the entire URL and you can confirm.